# Android-How to create searchView in toolbar

Tags: java, android, toolbar, searchview

i want add searchView in toolbar.just i want the query entered by user i no need to search.my problem is when i run my app it crashes do no where i did wrong can anyone help me.

here is my **main_menu.xml** code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
android:id="@+id/search"
android:title="Search"
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SerachView"
app:showAsAction="always"
/>
```

And my **mainActivity.java** code

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
SearchView searchView=(SearchView)findViewById(R.id.search);
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
     //   Toast.makeText(this,query,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        return false;
    }
});
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Thank in Advance.

Comment: post your logcat error

Comment: You've misspelled `SearchView` – `app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"`.

Comment: First, you misspelled `SearchView` in your layout. Second, you must find your `SearchView` by: `MenuItem myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem( R.id.action_search); searchView = (SearchView) myActionMenuItem.getActionView();`

Comment: Yes,i corrected the searchView eventhough my app crashes.

Comment: post your logcat error

Comment: ThankYou @RoShan Shan You solved my problem Thank you So much